# Vertical wheel view: how to make the selected item editable?

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I'm using [`kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView`](https://github.com/chemalarrea/Android-wheel/blob/master/wheel/src/kankan/wheel/widget/WheelView.java) to include a vertical picker wheel view in my app. The items in my WheelView are `EditText`s, and I want the selected item to gain the focus when tapped.

I understand that `WheelView` is a direct subclass of `View` and not a `ViewGroup`, and its `LinearLayout` field (which contains the items) is not a real child, but is only used to draw the contents. How can I move the focus to one of the `EditText` items (and show the keyboard to actually edit the text)? Can I simply add something in the `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)`? Do I need to make the `WheelView` extend a `ViewGroup` like `FrameLayout` and add its `LinearLayout` field as its child?

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found a solution to this problem. The code is a bit complex, but basically I've created a new custom view, `EditableWheelView`, which extends `FrameLayout` and inflates an XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView
        android:id="@+id/editable_scroll_view_wheel_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/editable_scroll_view_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

</merge>
```

with an internal `FrameLayout` which allows me to add an `EditText` on top of the WheelView.

In the code, every time an item of the internal `WheelView` is selected, I recreate it with the same adapter and add it to `editable_scroll_view_container`. I also manage to copy the value from the internal `WheelView` to the `EditText` in the `FrameLayout` container. When the item is deselected, I simply remove the contents of `editable_scroll_view_container`.